# JVM tuning for better Solr performance

Tags: performance, tomcat, solr, jvm, java-6

Now we are using Solr1.4 in Master/Slave mode and want to improve the performance for Slave query.

The biggest issue for us is the index file is about 30G.

The Slave server config as below:
Dell PC Server: 48G memory and 2 CPU; 
RedHat 64 Linux;
JDK64 1.6.0_22;
Tomcat 6.18.

Our current JAVA_OPTS is "–Xms2048M –Xmx20480 –server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:SurvivorRatio=2"

Do you have more suggestion for JAVA_OPTS?

Answer (score 3):

The JAVA_OPTS seem fine. quite a few questions :-

1. Is you max for 20GB ram peaking out ? can you check the memory stats as to whats the max utilized ?
2. Is there any heavy processing happening on Slave ? CPU stats ?
3. How are the queries ??? are you using highlighting ?
4. Whats the number of results you are returing for single query ?
5. what do your cache stats say ? are they utilized properly ?
6. Is your index optimized ??
7. do you use warming queries to improve performance on the slow running queries ?
8. If the above seems fine, can you consider enabling the http caching ?

Answer (score 1):

use the following opts

-XX:+UseCompressedOops
 (This will help in reducing the heap size)

-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis